# NameError for globals

Tags: python

In some Python modules, I have code like this:

```
try:
    someGlobal
except NameError:
    someGlobal = []
```

This can be important in case I want to support module reloading and some certain object must not be overwritten (e.g. because I know that it is referred to directly).

Many editors (e.g. PyCharm) mark this as an error. Is there some other way to write the same code which is more Python idiomatic? Or is this already Python idiomatic and it's a fault of the editors to complain about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with

```
if 'someGlobal' not in dir():
    someGlobal = 23
```

This has the advantage of simplicity, but can be a bit slow if the module has a lot of globals, since `dir()` is a `list` and the `in` operator on it is `O(N)`.

For speed, and at a modest disadvantage in terms of simplicity,

```
if 'someGlobal' not in vars():
    someGlobal = 23
```

which should be faster since `vars()` is a `dict`, so the `in` operator on it is `O(1)`.

Comment: So this is idiomatic Python? And why is `dir()` more simple than `vars()`?

Comment: Not especially idiomatic (it's rare to want to check if a global already exists in order to preserve it across `reload`s, which are quite rare in themselves!) but not an error of any kind, either.  As for `dir` vs `vars`, I think every Python user knows the former (often used to interactively explore a module &c) but fewer know about the latter; so maybe it's more about expected **familiarity** rather than actual **simplicity**.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* an error, at least given the information availale to the editor.  So the editor isn't wrong; it is just that you are specifically coding for that error.

Comment: The editor can also see that I'm esp handling this error. If this is Python idiomatic, the editor should not complain about it. So the question mainly is, is this Python idiomatic?